# How to make a dynamic countdown timer using django and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, web

From views.py I am returning date and time to my HTML page. But unable to use that date and time to set a countdown timer using Javascript
For e.g

```
return render(request,'page.html',{'date':i.date,'time':i.time,'hours':i.hours})
```

time represents starting time 
hours represent total countdown time 
'i' is python object

Comment: Some suggestions for writing a better question: There are several parts to this. You need to show what you have already done and be more specific about what you need help with.  For example, do you need help figuring out how to calculate time difference between now and the set alarm? Or in passing the time to the JS in the right format? Or creating a timer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. I got it from w3schools.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();
                            // date and time to end above

var x = setInterval(function() {


  var now = new Date().getTime();


  var distance = countDownDate - now;


  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";


  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```